# dynamic number of ggvis plots in Rshiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

it is a simplified version of a shiny app I am trying to build.
I want the user to be able to control the number of plots created by ggvis.
(In the full version, the user is also able to interactively choose the variables to be plotted.)
But apparently, it is not responding very well.

ui.r

```
        shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

      headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),

      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5)
      ),

      mainPanel(
        # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    ))
```

server.r

```
    max_plots <- 5

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
      output$plots <- renderUI({
        plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
          plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
          ggvisOutput(plotname)
        })

        # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
        # to display properly.
        do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
      })

      # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
      # are visible on the web page.
      for (i in 1:max_plots) {
        # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
        # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
        # of when the expression is evaluated.
        local({
          my_i <- i
          plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
          cars %>% 
            ggvis(~speed, ~ dist) %>%
            layer_points() %>%
            bind_shiny(plotname)
        })
      }
    })
```